# Images got blurred

Tags: css, html, blogger

In my blog www.bankers-adda.co.in  images at the home page are getting blurred while these images appear good when we open that post. Can anyone tell how to fix..   [My blog address](http://www.bankers-adda.co.in)

Comment: They got blurred, because the real image size is 72px, and you are increasing real height and width of image.

Comment: How can keep this of original size.. Please tell.. I'm new to html and css. I know only basics

Comment: you are using small image in home page use this one(https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-C9MZV6Q7Lrc/V6UULq0QSaI/AAAAAAAABpk/Lmiwsek9E3Yk23GHPZN2rF07kkTbCHr5QCLcB/s1600/Untitled-min-min-min-min-min.png)

Comment: @zeeshan, you should take bigger images, maybe bigger than the image parent width. When you take bigger image, you can specify a max width for image, and the image quality will remain.

Comment: @zeeshan, I can see that the images, when you are inside the link have bigger size. Take those images! For example here: http://www.bankers-adda.co.in/2016/08/important-news-agencies-of-different-countries-pdf.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the image with the low resolution with larger images. 
E.g for this image 
`<img alt="Important News Agencies of the World" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-C9MZV6Q7Lrc/V6UULq0QSaI/AAAAAAAABpk/Lmiwsek9E3Yk23GHPZN2rF07kkTbCHr5QCLcB/s72-c/Untitled-min-min-min-min-min.png">`

the Original Size is 72px*72px, but you scale it up to 210*210px. So you have to replace the low resolution images. Then it should be fine.

But it could be that this are Auto Generated images (because of the path and the image name) so don't wondering if its not working... maybe its a problem with your blogging software.